Clipping with Image and overlayed Icon button in Flutter
Working on image selection and trying to make mimic this display. 
I know I will need a stack widget and ClipRRect but not sure how to do the X button in the top right where it clips the image.

Can you share sample code that will reproduce the same issue

theres no issue, not sure how to display an image like in the sample image.  Trying to figure out how to do it

Please try this:
    Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 8,
          right: 8,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2440003.jpg'))),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                color: Colors.grey),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.close_rounded,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )

This is the result:


Thanks, had to tweak a couple things to make it work in my layout, but that got me in the right direction and was able to get it working
